# API Platform - Resource without Operation

Tags: php, api, symfony, api-platform.com

is it possible to usw API Resources without operations ? I have entities that are related in e.g. Account but should not have their own GET Endpoints.

If thats not possible, is it possible to remove those Endpoints from the swagger and redoc documentation ?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Docs: https://api-platform.com/docs/core/operations/#enabling-and-disabling-operations

```
<?php
// api/src/Entity/Book.php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;

/**
 * ...
 * @ApiResource(
 *     collectionOperations={},
 *     itemOperations={}
 * )
 */
class Book
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But i think that solution is wrong. If you just remove the operations, the IRIs are not creates properly.

Comment: "If you do not want to allow access to the resource item (i.e. you don't want a GET item operation), instead of omitting it altogether, you should instead declare a GET item operation which returns HTTP 404 (Not Found), so that the resource item can still be identified by an IRI" (docs linked by PaulRoth).  Example: #[ApiResource(
    collectionOperations: [],
    itemOperations: [
        'get' => [
            'controller' => NotFoundAction::class,
            'read' => false,
            'output' => false,
        ],
    ],
)]